# How to split the string into variables/parameters to pass to another script?

Tags: string, bash, awk, tokenize

I've got a list of files (with full paths) that I need to split into tokens to be able to pass to another script/command.  Looking at the style of the strings, I figure awk is the right tool to use, but I just can't seem to figure out how to do this given that the number of tokens vary by line.

Given a filename `./some/path/to/artifact_name/v1.2.3/filename.jar`, I need to be able to extract the following:

- filename - the string following the final / : filename.jar
- version - the string following the / preceeding the filename : v1.2.3
- artifact name - the string following the / preceeding the version : artifact_name
- group name - the rest of the path, with all / replaced by . : some.path.to

For example, given:

```
./com/eric/ics/BillP/3.5.11/BillP-3.5.11.jar
- filename: BillP-3.5.11.jar
-version: 3.5.11
-artifact: BillP
-group: com.eric.ics
```

My biggest complication becomes that the number of folders representing the group can change.  For ex: `./com/eric/some/other/pkg/BillP/3.5.11/BillP-3.5.11.jar` would be just as valid, except that the group would then be `com.eric.some.other.pkg`.

My goal is to pass these 4 params to a separate script once I've managed to extract them, but I cannot seem to figure out the easiest way to do this.  Is awk the right tool for this?  Is there something better/easier to use?

Comment: Was a very tough call which solution to mark as correct.  anubhava solution uses awk (which is what my original question asked for), but I have to give extra credit to HansKluder for a simple (although not as elegant), straight-forward solution.  KISS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk or perl to print all the components and pipe that into `read` to assign them to different variable names, or use the less elegant commands `dirname` and `basename` several times to get the components one by one, storing them immediately into variables that you can use as parameters to call other scripts. Depends on what your like.

```
#!/bin/bash

p="$1"
file="$(basename "$p")"
p="$(dirname "$p")"
version="$(basename "$p")"
p="$(dirname "$p")"
artifact="$(basename "$p")"
group="$(dirname "$p" | tr / . | sed 's+\.*++')"

echo file=$file version=$version artifact=$artifact group=$group
```

Now you have these 4 parameters in 4 variables which you can pass to whatever you like.

Comment: Nice solution.  Definitely not as elegant, but very simple and straight forward.  Sometimes KISS is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Using gnu-awk:

```
awk -F/ -v OFS=. '{f=$NF;v=$(NF-1);a=$(NF-2); NF-=3; sub(/^[^[:alnum:]]+/, ""); 
  printf "-filename: %s\n-version: %s\n-artifact: %s\n-group: %s\n\n", f, v, a, $0 }' file
-filename: BillP-3.5.11.jar
-version: 3.5.11
-artifact: BillP
-group: com.eric.ics

-filename: BillP-3.5.11.jar
-version: 3.5.11
-artifact: BillP
-group: com.eric.some.other.pkg

cat file
./com/eric/ics/BillP/3.5.11/BillP-3.5.11.jar
./com/eric/some/other/pkg/BillP/3.5.11/BillP-3.5.11.jar
```

---

**EDIT:** To call a secondary script using these params:

```
awk -F/ -v OFS=. '{f=$NF;v=$(NF-1);a=$(NF-2); NF-=3; sub(/^[^[:alnum:]]+/, ""); 
  system("./script.sh " f " " v " " a " " $0) }' file
```

Comment: And that script explains why I wasn't able to figure it out myself. :)  Is there an easy way once those params are extracted to call a secondary script though?  Was hoping to do it from within awk, but I can't find anything that allows me to do that.  Otherwise, I guess I just have to pipe to a script.

Comment: Yes sure awk can call your secondary script also. Both `system` and `getline` have support for calling external command.

Comment: Updated answer to show how to call another script using these parameters.

Comment: You can also pass the output into `read`. Just, it's a bit tricky. `echo a b c | read x y z` won't work because `read x y z ` happens in a subshell. You need something like `read x y z <<<$(echo a b c)`. Now replace `echo a b c` by the awk script and you are done. Just keep in mind that sometimes blanks can mess up everything.

Comment: @HansKlünder: **Process substitution** way using `read x y z < <(echo a b c)` is considered more efficient in BASH.

Comment: Thanks for that hint, anubhava. I somehow got used to these `<<<` but the process substitution you showed me the 2nd time now is clearly prefrerable, and I should finally keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    
use strict; use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @list = split /\//;
    print map { $_ . "\t" . pop(@list) . "\n" }
        qw/-filename: -version: -artifact:/;
    print "-group:\t\t", join(".", @list[1..$#list]), "\n\n";
}

__DATA__
./com/eric/ics/ccc/BillP/3.5.11/BillP-3.5.11.jar
./com/eric/ics/BillP/3.5.11/BillP-3.5.11.jar
./com/eric/ics/xxx/yyy/BillP/3.5.11/BillP-3.5.11.jar
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
-filename:      BillP-3.5.11.jar
-version:       3.5.11
-artifact:      BillP
-group:         com.eric.ics.ccc

-filename:      BillP-3.5.11.jar
-version:       3.5.11
-artifact:      BillP
-group:         com.eric.ics

-filename:      BillP-3.5.11.jar
-version:       3.5.11
-artifact:      BillP
-group:         com.eric.ics.xxx.yyy
```

Comment: I thought of regexs first, but my problem with using regexs like that is that they are positionally dependent, and like I said, the number of subfolders can change prior to the actual filename.